# Mysql query failed to execute

Tags: php, mysql

Why this code does not work in the database?

```
$sql = 
UPDATE users_information INNER JOIN users ON users.id = user_id SET following_count = :following_count WHERE user_id = :user_id;
```

$data :

```
["following_count" => "following_count + 1" , "user_id" => "1273"]
```

execute return false

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`following_count + 1` is **expression**,  You cannot bind expressions, only values. So, rewrite your query as:

```
$sql = "
UPDATE users_information INNER JOIN users ON users.id = user_id 
SET following_count = following_count + 1 
WHERE user_id = :user_id";
```

And in `$data` you pass only `user_id`:

```
$data = ["user_id" => "1273"];
```

Also, it's unclear to me what's the point of using join, why not simple query:

```
$sql = "
UPDATE users_information 
SET following_count = following_count + 1 
WHERE user_id = :user_id";
```

Comment: No security problem?

Comment: Sure, no problem.

Answer (score 0):

["following_count" => "following_count + 1" , "user_id" => "1273"] .

> Here "following_count + 1"  its a string .

Make it Integer. Or if its a string then in database change the type 
as varchar.

data should be like the following:

```
$following_count = $following_count + 1;
["following_count" => "some_number(from following_count value)" , "user_id" => "1273"]
```